# Order by "day" of a date field in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to retrieve some data from my events table using Laravel eloquent. I want to pull all events back for a specific month (which is working) but I want to order the data by the **day of the month**, not the whole date. So my output would look like:

```
Jan 1st 2000
Jan 1st 2010
Jan 1st 2020
Jan 2nd 2005
Jan 3rd 2006
Jan 3rd 2010
```

I was hoping there would something like this (but can't find anything similar):

> ->orderByDay('date_field')

Thank you!

Comment: You want to get it ordered or insert it ordered ?

Comment: It does, as does OMR below. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no  orderByDay in laravel!
perhaps you have a column with name 'day' and the generator generate a method called orderByDay to order by that date field ... not the day of that date field

however ...
you can use orderByRaw :

```
->orderByRaw('DAY(date_field)')
```

Answer (score 1):

This will sort descending.

->sortBy() will sort ascending.

```
return Model::all()->sortByDesc(function($element) {
    return Carbon::parse($element->created_at)->format('d');
});
```

Edit: This will use PHP to sort the array. OMR's answer will use MySQL, which should be faster than PHP sort.